# Apache2 Reverse Proxy with Play

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

I tried to configure apache2 reverse proxy:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass           /stag http://127.0.0.1:9001
    ProxyPassReverse    /stag http://127.0.0.1:9001

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

My Play instance run at `localhost:9001`, when I tried to call `http://192.168.1.10:9001` it success, and cannot load all the files (image, css, js) inside the `public` folder of play project when try to call `http://192.168.1.10/stag`. When I check the url (using F12 on google Chrome) it comes to `http://192.168.1.10/public/images/logo.png` it supposed to `http://192.168.1.10/stag/public/images/logo.png`.

My question, **is there a problem with my configuration of apache2 reverse proxy?**

Answer (score 0):

Apache config is good, the a problem is in the contents of your HTML.

If your HTML points to the root..

```
<img src="/public/images/logo.png">
```

Then it points to the root, and the `/stag` prefix that your proxy is effectively adding is ignored.  Your `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` don't translate this for you.

On the other hand, if you allow the path to be relative..

```
<img src="public/images/logo.png">
```

Then, the relative path is kept and the resource can load.

There's also tools like `mod_proxy_html` that attempt to translate the paths in your HTML files, but they aren't foolproof; the better option is to make the contents work within the proxy.

Comment: No different if change to `public/images/logo.png`. I'll try to store at Tomcat and reverse proxy the tomcat.